# Peugeot 207 Handbrake lever loose with handbrake on

Tags: peugeot, handbrake

I would like to begin by saying that my mechanical experience with cars only stretches as far as I've seen on Top Gear. My knowledge about cars isn't any better than a 5 year olds.

Now then, I've got a 2008 Peugeot 207. I'm in a rural town so the car isn't used very much, haven't used it for 6-8 weeks until today 
I've had several problems with this car, one of which is that the handbrake lever gets completely loose. Normally this isn't a big of a problem and I just get it fixed during regular maintenance. This time however the handbrake was on when it happened and the car is now stuck in my driveway. The last time i used the car it was just fine, didn't hear any sort of noise or anything when I was turning it off.

Now I´m turning to you guys because i want to at least turn the handbrake off so the car can be moved.

I managed to get a look inside where the handbrake lever is and the wires there were attached and the lever pulls the wires if i pull it high enough but the wires don't seem to pull back on the lever. I don't think i can explain that any better.

Now, what would my next step be?

Comment: So I understand, you are saying when you pull the e-brake handle, you don't get any resistance, then after it's "adjusted" by the technician, it's good (has resistance and holds the vehicle) but then over time it loosens up and you no longer can use the handbrake for anything useful? But right now the brakes are stuck in the "on" position and the car will not move?

Comment: Almost, it doesnt get looser over time, it always happens all of a sudden, it is working perfectly and then suddenly it isnt. And yes it is stuck on at the moment.

Comment: Gotcha ... thanks for the clarification. Not that I'm any closer to getting you an answer. Your e-brake may be rusted into place and not releasing (the brake pads or caliper or whatever). How you'd go about getting them released is the question. You could try taking the rear wheels off and see if you can get at the e-brake mechanism from there. Not sure if it is an inside the hat system or if the cables are directly connected to the caliper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a mechanic to look at it for me. Turns out that it was just stuck after all the bad weather that has been going on for the past few weeks and he fixed it by hitting the wire with a wrench a couple of times.